# slickGrid: textEditor: focus does not fire when enter field

Tags: editor, slickgrid

This is a bit strange:

```
function myEditor(args) {
   this.init = function () {
      $input = $("<INPUT id='tags' class='editor-text' />");
      $input.appendTo(args.container);
   },

   $input.focus().select();
   this.init();
} 
$input.focus( function(e){ ... })
```

Whatever I try, it does not fire. What am I doing wrong?

Or, question rephrased:
What event do I need to catch in what element when I want to do something when the cell (-editor) is entered?

Comment: Where and how are you using this editor in the grid? Can you post your grid initialization code?

Comment: did you find an answer for this? please advise!